# My Signatures File Got Corrupted everytime i create new user with signature

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I Have a problem, every time i create new user with signature. The File size go 0kb and cant be open, i try reach the file it work but doesnt show.

So I have this Controller to store new user with a new signature.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Save Signature from data URL to storage
        $signatureData = $request->signature;
        $fileName = time() . '.png';
        $filePath = 'public/signatures/' . $fileName;  // Save to storage/app/public
        $imageData = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $signatureData));
        Storage::put($filePath, $imageData);

        // Validasi dan penyimpanan data user
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'user_code' => $request->user_code,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'signature_path' => 'signatures/' . $fileName,  // Save part of path todatabase
        ]);

        // Add role(Jabatans) to user with pivot table
        $user->jabatans()->attach($request->jabatan_id);
        Session::flash('success', 'User Berhasil Dibuat');
        return redirect()->route('user-create');
    }
```

And this code block for signature i got

```
<div class="mb-3">
                     <label for="signature">Signature</label>
                     <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200 style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
                            <button type="button" id="clearSignature" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Clear
                                Signature</button>
</div>
```

And this my Javascript to use the signature-pad library

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
    var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

    // Function to check if the form is completely filled out
    function isFormValid(formId) {
        const form = document.getElementById(formId);
        return form.checkValidity();
    }

    // Function to display SweetAlert confirmation
    function showConfirmationAlert() {
        if (isFormValid('userForm')) { 
            // Replace 'userForm' with your form's ID
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: 'Do you want to submit this form?',
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    // Submit the form
                    document.getElementById('userForm').submit(); 
                    // Replace 'userForm' with your form's ID

                    // Show success alert
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Success!',
                        'Your form has been submitted.',
                        'success'
                    );
                }
            });
        } else {
            Swal.fire(
                'Error!',
                'Please fill out all required fields.',
                'error'
            );
        }
    }

    // Add an event listener to the clear signature button
    document.getElementById('clearSignature').addEventListener('click', function() {
        signaturePad.clear();
    });

    // Add an event listener to the submit button
    document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Check the signature first
        if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Please provide your signature.',
            });
            return;
        }

        // Then, check for user code duplication
        const userCode = document.getElementById('user_code').value;

        fetch('/check-usercode', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    user_code: userCode
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.exists) {
                    // If the user code already exists, show a warning with SweetAlert
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'User code already exists!',
                    });
                } else {
                    // If the user code is unique, display a form submission confirmation
                    showConfirmationAlert();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    });
</script>
```

*Edit The Whole JS in My blade

So I Tried a reach for preview the signature image and the image didnt show up, i already link my storage/app/public/signatures/. It worked, and the file was created the problem is the file always cant be open or corrupted. Previously it worked and then it didnt :D

Comment: looks like you are not using signaturepad correctly, show full js for it

Comment: I don't see the request being sent anywhere with the `signature` value passed

Comment: Yes, looks like your just not sending the signature data back from teh browser to your php code so the code is just creating a blank file.

Answer (score 0):

you are not posting your signature to controller method,

if `check-usercode` is the route for your mentioned controller method

modify it like this

```
fetch('/check-usercode', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    user_code: userCode,
                    name: name, // also noticed you have name in the controller
                    signature: canvas.toDataURL()
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                }
            })
```